# Hide text if viewing page on phone (not tablet)

Tags: php

We've just been editing the index.php file of a Joomla template to add some content to a page, where a module position does not exist.

This is fine however I would like to hide the text if the page is being viewed on a phone but not a tablet or any larger screen size. Is this possible and if so, what PHP code do I need to do this?

Kind regards

James

Answer (score 1):

You can target mobile resolutions this with CSS media queries. So in your template's CSS file, you could do something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .element {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You will of course need to change `.element` to the class or `#id` of the element you're trying to hide.

Comment: If the template is based on Bootstrap 2.3, you can even just add the class `hidden-phone`

Comment: Hi guys,

Thank you both for your replies. The problem is the content is not in a module, rather in the PHP code of the index.php file for the template, I therefore need the PHP code to detect that it's a mobile phone and then hide the text if it is.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you please update your initial question with your code?

Comment: It's just text. It's the PHP code that I'm after, to hide the text.

Comment: You cant use PHP to hide/show elements on mobiles/desktop. Simply wrap your text in a `<div>` with a class and target that class in your CSS file as I've shown you